# ¿Cómo agregar una clase con nuevos estilos css a v-dialog, vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Me encuentro trabajando con vuetify, utilizando el siguiente v-dialog en un componente:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!--Indicador-->
      <v-dialog class="vdialognew" v-model="mostrarIndicator" persistent>
        <v-content>
          <v-container fluid fill-height>
            <v-layout align-center justify-center>
                <cube-shadow class="spinnerRotate"></cube-shadow>
            </v-layout>
          </v-container>
        </v-content>
      </v-dialog>
    <!-------------->
  </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
.vdialognew {
  box-shadow: none !important;
  max-width: 610px !important;
}
</style>
```

Como veran en v-dialog he agregado la clase vdialognew, para aplicar esos nuevos estilos, pero al cargar el contenido revisando en la consola del navegador, veo que no le aplica la clase vdialognew, unicamente. De igual forma si utilizo la propiedad `style` dentro de la etiqueta `v-dialog`, no me funciona.
Como puedo realizar tal cambio.

Dicha modificación la estoy realizando para eliminar el cuadro que se ve atrás del cuadrado verde:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece que el uso de `content-class` tiene conflictos al funcionar con `<style scoped>` tal como mencionan en el siguiente [enlace](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/5461).

Intenta colocando tu clase en el css global de tu aplicación y usa `content-class` como en el siguiente [ejemplo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jeJxZG). También puedes intentar quitar `scoped` de tu etiqueta `style`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado quitando 'scoped' de la etiqueta 'style' y utilizando content-class.

Comment: +1 Gracias por indagar en el problema, no había tenido en cuenta esto en mi respuesta .

Answer (score 2):

Según la [documentación](https://vuetifyjs.com/es-MX/components/dialogs) se puede añadir una clase personalizada con el prop `content-class`

Ejm

```
<v-dialog v-model="mostrarIndicator" persistent content-class="vdialognew" >
   ....
```

Para este ejemplo se añade el valor para el ancho del dialogo, usando la clase. `vdialognew`

```js
Vue.component('example-dialog',{

data: function () {
    return {
      mostrarIndicator: true
    }
  },
  template: `<v-app id="inspire"> <v-dialog
       v-model="mostrarIndicator" persistent content-class="vdialognew" 
      >
  
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title
            class="headline grey lighten-2"
            primary-title
          >
            Privacy Policy
          </v-card-title>
  
          <v-card-text>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </v-card-text>
  
          <v-divider></v-divider>
  

        </v-card>
      </v-dialog> </v-app>`,
    

});
new Vue({
  el: '#app'

})
```

```css
.vdialognew {
  box-shadow: none !important;
  max-width: 610px !important;
  width : 2500px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.1/dist/vuetify.min.css">

<div id="app">
   <example-dialog />
</div>
```

Comment: Lo he realizado, guiándome con la documentación, pero no aplica el estilo.

Comment: @JG_GJ revise el DOM, se añade la clase al dialogo?  o qué estilos busca añadir, quizá el error sea de su CSS , debería funcionar, intentaré añadir un ejemplo.

Comment: Revisando el DOM, veo que si aplica la clase, pero al buscar la clase entre los estilos "Pestaña Styles", no aparece la clase con su propiedades y pues al final no aplica los estilos.